# Primitive hexagonal with the atom storage ABCBCACAB

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

I'm currently stuck on a question where my closepacked structure is netiher fcc or hcp, and instead it is ABCBCACAB. I'm supposed to calculate how many atoms there is in primitive unit cell (hexagonal), I'm quite unsure of how I should approach this question. How do you start on this kind of question?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question at the chemistry stackexchange.

Comment: Sorry for  bringing this question to the wrong forum.

Comment: @SmarthBansal - really, this is solid state physics and crystal structure, not chemistry (although I will allow that there is some overlap). To the OP - how are you going to define your primitive cell here? Answer that question first.

Comment: I realize that I should put some effort into this question, but I thought this had more with a mindset to do more than anything, and it's seems like the kind of question where if you get a grasp of the main idea, you will easily solve it. I'm currently reading Charles Kittel, Solid-state physics but he is not mentioning atom storage to the point where I can start the problem.